# ARM template deployment to data factory not deploying linked service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a development environment Data factory resource that I'm trying to integrate with Azure Devops. In Azure Devops I set up a pipeline to [build the ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements) and then deploy it with override parameters to my production environment data factory. The issue I'm seeing are the linked services, which are defined in my development ARM template, are not being created in the production data factory.

Here are the relevant parts of my Azure Devops pipelines:

The arm deployment task:

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: ARM Template Deployment
    inputs:
      azureResourceManagerConnection: <service connection>
      subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}'
      resourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}'
      location: ${{ parameters.location }}
      csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplate/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
      csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplate/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
      overrideParameters: >
        -factoryName ${{ parameters.targetDataFactoryName }}
        ${{ parameters.overrideParameters }}
```

The caller pipeline (I am using a template):

```
    jobs:
      - template: datafactory.yml@templates
        parameters:
          subscriptionId: <subscription id>
          resourceGroupName: <resource group name>
          location: 'East US 2'
          targetDataFactoryName: <data factory name>
          sourceDataFactoryResourceId: <data factory id>
          overrideParameters: >
            -StorageAccountFolder_connectionString "$(StorageAccountFolder_connectionString_Stage)"
```

And the relevant section in my ARMTemplateForFactory.json file:

```
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": "Data Factory name",
            "defaultValue": "something"
        },
        "StorageAccountFolder_connectionString": {
            "type": "secureString",
            "metadata": "Secure string for 'connectionString' of 'StorageAccountFolder'"
        }
    },
```

**Edit:** Nothing appears to be creating or updating despite the ARM template successfully deploying. In the activity log it also indicates the data factory resource was updated.

[image]

Comment: How are you building the Data Factory artifacts for the pipeline? Are you running the npm utility or deploying via the adf_publish branch?

Comment: I am building via the npm utility. I downloaded the artifact from the pipeline build and I verified the parameters exist in the development ARMTemplateForFactory.json and ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json files

Comment: actually it appears that nothing is being created or updated going from my dev to prod data factory. The trigger I created in dev does not show up in the prod data factory after a successful ARM deployment.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer; however, some guidance with this approach as there are some YAML pipeline templates written to cover this. [CI/CD Pipeline](https://github.com/JFolberth/adf_pipelines_yaml_ci_cd), [Build Template](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne/blob/main/stages/adf_build_stage.yml), and [Deploy Template](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne/blob/main/stages/adf_deploy_stage.yml) I think one piece that could be missing is the separate parameters file for each environment, also if possible, try to download the azure-pipeline-expanded.yml to troubleshoot

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I ended up figuring out the issue. The data factory had been git integrated so I was seeing only the resources on the main branch. Once I disconnected I was able to view my new resources.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that I didn't check for sooner was that this particular Data Factory was already git integrated (it was setup by someone else) and I was only seeing resources on the 'main' branch. Once I disconnected and was back to "live" mode only then did my pipeline-created resources showed up. Something to keep in mind if you are a DF noob like me.